# Encrypt data stream to specific user in Active Directory

Tags: c#, encryption, active-directory

How would I go about encrypting some data so that it can be sent in a way that the same Active Directory user can decrypt it?

The goal is to encrypt the data, send that encrypted data to another computer through TCP, and then decrypt it.

This would be trivial to do with public / private keys, but I don't want to hardcode anything, or otherwise depend on a specific Active Directory environment.

Comment: There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to us when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do.

Comment: Just use httpS REST API. Secure, widespread, easy to manage, many guides, many examples. VS generates those boilerplate projects for you when you choose ASP.NET Core Web API. Don't fall into the pit of various *specific* protocols, you will eventually switch to them if there will be need or when you will be more proficient to distinguish.